# Fabric Crashlytics Closed Bugs Behavior

Tags: crashlytics

Using Crashlytics with Twitter Fabric SDK and curious when you fix and close the bug (set status as closed) and lets say it come back again in a future build, does the bug get re-opened?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike from the Fabric team here.

If you close an issue for a version, then a new issue will be created if the bug re-appears in the next version. We will also attempt to mark the two as related, which you can see at the bottom of an issue.

Comment: in our project a bug is created if it re-appears in an old version. Is this a bug within Fabric / Crashlytics? Where could i submit a bug of this?

Comment: That's expected as we can't rely on semantic versioning since not every app uses that. Bugs are re-opened if it occurs in a version outside the known set of versions that already experienced the crash.